# How change variable from function setTimeout inside an loop

Tags: javascript

How alternate value to variable dinamic_delay using conditions described below?

```
var emails = []; // array 
var number = 5;
var count = 0;
var dinamic_delay;
for (i = 0; i < emails.length; i++) {
    count++;
    if (count == number) {
        dinamic_delay = 3000;
        count = 0; // resset count
    } else {
        dinamic_delay = 500;
    }
    setTimeout(function (i) {
        sendemail(email[i]);
    }, dinamic_delay * i, i);
}
```

Comment: Yes in javascript. Sorry !!!

Comment: I can't tell what you are asking. What exactly do you want to happen? In what way does the code you've provided not do what you want?

Comment: From 5 to 5 emails setTimeout  i want to wait 30 seconds. In rest, 0.5 seconds...

Comment: What is the problem with your current code?

Comment: dinamic_delay is not changed , have value 0.5 seconds all the time...

Comment: `dinamic_delay` is definitely changing, though maybe not to the value you expect. When `count` reaches a value of `5`, `dinamic_delay` will be assigned a value of `3000`. At that time, `i` will have a value of `4`, so `setTimeout` will be called with a delay of `12000 (3000 * 4)` (12 seconds).

Comment: That's correct, but setTimeout does not even take that break of 12 seconds at multiplication by 4. (ex i = 4).
I can not figure out where the problem is.
Basically, I want for each email to take a 0.5 second break and 5 out of 5 emails to take a 30 second break.

Comment: Example:
email1 - 0.5 sec wait..
email2 - 0.5 sec wait..
email3 - 0.5 sec wait..
email4 - 0.5 sec wait..
**email5 - 30 sec wait..**
email6 - 0.5 sec wait..
email7 - 0.5 sec wait..
email8 - 0.5 sec wait..
email9 - 0.5 sec wait..
**email10 - 30 sec wait..**
email11 - 0.5 sec wait..
email12 - 0.5 sec wait..
email13 - 0.5 sec wait..
email14 - 0.5 sec wait..
**email15 - 30 sec wait..**
email16 - 0.5 sec wait..
email17 - 0.5 sec wait..
email18 - 0.5 sec wait..
email19 - 0.5 sec wait..
**email20 - 30 sec wait..**
................

Answer (score 0):

I had to remind myself how setTimeout works:

a. setTimeout(myfunction(), 5000)   -calls the function after at least 5000 millisecs from now (when this code is executed)

b. setTimeout(myfunction(), 5000)   -calls the function after at least 5000 millisecs from now (when this code is executed)

in other words there is not an automatic 10,000 millisec before b is called, e.g. might by 6000 ms

setInterval is useful if you want to call things at regular intervals.

The example below displays console.log message 3, 3, 3, 3, 10 seconds & repeats until the final email.

```
    const bigDelay_c = 10000;  //secs
    const smallDelay_c = 3000;  //secs
    const totalEmails_c = 18;   //total to process

    var totalEmailsProcessed = 0; //running total
    var timerId = 0;

    timerId = setInterval(alertFunc, smallDelay_c);


    function alertFunc() {

        //sendEmail logic here
        var currentdate = new Date();
        totalEmailsProcessed++;
        console.log(totalEmailsProcessed, currentdate.getHours() + ":" +
            currentdate.getMinutes() + ":" + currentdate.getSeconds());
        clearInterval(timerId);  //stop interval repeating

        //stop if all emails have been processed
        if (totalEmailsProcessed >= totalEmails_c) {
            console.log('all emails processed');
            return;
        }


        //5th item in every 5 get bigDelay_c
        if (totalEmailsProcessed % 5 == 4)
            timerId = setInterval(alertFunc, bigDelay_c);
        else
            timerId = setInterval(alertFunc, smallDelay_c);


    }
```

Comment: So your proposal is that instead of setTimeout, to use the setInterval function?

Comment: I've added an example of how to use setInterval, delay in secs 3,3,3,3, 10,3,3,3,3,10 etc